# How to read .csv polygon data with sf?

Tags: r, polygon, sf

I am trying to read a .csv file where each row contains information about a polygon. The polygon geometry information is stored in a `shape` column such as `'longitude latitude altitude accuracy; ...'`.

Here is a simplified example with a single square polygon:

```
structure(list(field = "parcel_a", shape = "5 50 0 0.5; 20 50 0 0.5; 5 40 0 0.5; 20 40 0 0.5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

How can I read this data format with `sf` in R? I would also be interested to know where does this format come from.

Comment: The ordering of those four points doesn't make a square, but a "bow-tie" polygon that crosses in the middle. Is this a real example or have you made it and not noticed its an invalid polygon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its close to being like a part of a WKT format string.

You have:

```
"5 50 0 0.5; 20 50 0 0.5; 5 40 0 0.5; 20 40 0 0.5"
```

and the relevant WKT string would probably be:

```
"POLYGON ((5 50 0 0.5, 20 50 0 0.5, 5 40 0 0.5, 20 40 0 0.5))"
```

To convert to that and make `sf` objects...

1. Replace all semicolons with commas:

```
gsub(";",",",S$shape)
## [1] "5 50 0 0.5, 20 50 0 0.5, 5 40 0 0.5, 20 40 0 0.5"
```

2. Paste on the word "POLYGON" and some parentheses:

```
paste0("POLYGON ((",gsub(";",",",S$shape),"))")
## [1] "POLYGON ((5 50 0 0.5, 20 50 0 0.5, 5 40 0 0.5, 20 40 0 0.5))"
```

3. make into a data frame and use `st_as_sf`:

```
> st_as_sf(data.frame(g=paste0("POLYGON ((",gsub(";",",",S$shape),"))")),wkt="g")
## Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
## geometry type:  POLYGON
## dimension:      XYZM
## bbox:           xmin: 5 ymin: 40 xmax: 20 ymax: 50
## z_range:        zmin: 0 zmax: 0
## m_range:        mmin: 0.5 mmax: 0.5
## CRS:            NA
##                                g
## 1 POLYGON ZM ((5 50 0 0.5, 20...
```

Note this is a "POLYGON ZM" - you've got four coordinates in each part and this is treating the data as three dimensional with an "M" measurement.

and then at this point you realise that WKT needs the first point repeating in order to close the POLYGON. Oops.

So instead create it as a LINESTRING and coerce to POLYGON.

```
SQ = st_as_sf(
   data.frame(
    geom=paste0("LINESTRING (",gsub(";",",",S$shape),")")
   ),
   wkt="geom")

SQ = st_cast(SQ,"POLYGON")
plot(st_zm(SQ))
```

[image]

That's not a valid Simple Features polygon though because of the self-intersection...

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpful